# Почему d3.drag() работает по разному в зависимости от представления данных, привязываемых через .data?

Tags: d3.js, drag

Задача простая - сделать drag кружочков, но в осях. Столкнулся с проблемой. Ниже код, который реализует базовый функционал drag. Данные представлены массивом объектов. При выполнении кода кружки совершают ненужные прыжки.

```js
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 400])
  .range([0, 200])

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 400])
  .range([200, 0])

d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))


d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 200)')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

var data = [{
    x: 100,
    y: 200
  },
  {
    x: 300,
    y: 400
  }
];

var dragHandler = d3.drag()
.on('drag', dragged)

var circles = d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('circles')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return x(d.x)
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return y(d.y)
  })
  .attr('r', 10)
  .call(dragHandler)

function dragged(d) {
    d.x = x.invert(d3.event.x);
    d.y = y.invert(d3.event.y);

    d3.select(this)
    .attr('cx', x(d.x))
    .attr('cy', y(d.y))
};
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="300" height="300" viewbox="-50 -50 300 300"></svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

А если заменить массив объектов на массив массивов, то прыжки исчезают! Но перестает сохраняться начальное смещение кружка относительно курсора (при начале drag кружок центром прыгает на курсор).

```js
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 400])
  .range([0, 200])

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 400])
  .range([200, 0])

d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))


d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 200)')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

var data = [
  [100, 200],
  [300, 400]
];

var dragHandler = d3.drag()
  .on('drag', dragged)

var circles = d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('circles')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return x(d[0])
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return y(d[1])
  })
  .attr('r', 10)
  .call(dragHandler)

function dragged(d) {
  d[0] = x.invert(d3.event.x);
  d[1] = y.invert(d3.event.y);

  d3.select(this)
    .attr('cx', x(d[0]))
    .attr('cy', y(d[1]))
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="300" height="300" viewbox="-50 -50 300 300"></svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Почему так происходит?
Если сделать масштаб 1:1 то проблема не уйдет. А вот если вообще убрать масштабы и работать "в пикселях" то в первом варианте все ок.

Answer (score 0):

Обработчик drag должен знать как найти необходимые ему данные, по умолчанию он ищет их в массиве, поведение это можно переопределить вот так:

```
var dragHandler = d3.drag()
  .subject(d => [d.x, d.y])
  .on('drag', dragged)
```

```js
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 400])
  .range([0, 200])

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 400])
  .range([200, 0])

d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))


d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 200)')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

var data = [{
    x: 100,
    y: 200
  },
  {
    x: 300,
    y: 400
  }
];

var dragHandler = d3.drag()
  /// я добавил это
  .subject(d => [d.x, d.y])
.on('drag', dragged)

var circles = d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('circles')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return x(d.x)
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return y(d.y)
  })
  .attr('r', 10)
  .call(dragHandler)

function dragged(d) {
    d.x = x.invert(d3.event.x);
    d.y = y.invert(d3.event.y);

    d3.select(this)
    .attr('cx', x(d.x))
    .attr('cy', y(d.y))
};
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="300" height="300" viewbox="-50 -50 300 300"></svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Тоже понял что надо что-то делать с subject. Но в вашем варианте не сохраняется начальное смещение между точкой курсора и кружком (он прыгает центром на курсор). Нашел решение которое изложил в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

На ответ натолкнул вот этот вопрос:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844949/d3-drag-event-behaviour-dragevent-x-and-dragevent-y-values-source

Как я понял свойства .x, .y прям "забиты" в библиотеке и только с ними будет сохраняться начальное смещение относительно курсора и центра круга.

В итоге добавил subject где указал данные d.x, d.y с учетом реальных масштабов по осям.

```
var dragHandler = d3.drag()
  .subject(function(d) {
    return {
      x: x(d.x),
      y: y(d.y)
    };
  })
  .on('drag', dragged)
```

```js
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 400])
  .range([0, 200])

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 400])
  .range([200, 0])

d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))


d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 200)')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

var data = [{
    x: 100,
    y: 200
  },
  {
    x: 300,
    y: 400
  }
];

//изменил только dragHandler
var dragHandler = d3.drag()
  .subject(function(d) {
    return {
      x: x(d.x),
      y: y(d.y)
    };
  })
  .on('drag', dragged)

var circles = d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('circles')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return x(d.x)
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return y(d.y)
  })
  .attr('r', 10)
  .call(dragHandler)

function dragged(d) {
  d.x = x.invert(d3.event.x);
  d.y = y.invert(d3.event.y);

  d3.select(this)
    .attr('cx', x(d.x))
    .attr('cy', y(d.y))
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="300" height="300" viewbox="-50 -50 300 300"></svg>
</body>

</html>
```